# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolver

Tags: jvm, websphere, apache-axis

getting the below exception after deploying the application in WAS8. using axis2 1.7.4 family with Woden api and impl 1.0M8. Will someone please help

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolvergetting 
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:65)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:815)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.loadClassPathModules(RepositoryListener.java:222)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:71)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:64)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadFromClassPath(DeploymentEngine.java:177)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:135)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:151)
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:144)
```

and later below I am getting classnotfoundexception also

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolver
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to bring your own web services implementation, you have to run with PARENT_LAST class loading (or, preferably, package your version of the web services implementation in a shared library with an isolated class loader) and disable the built-in web services engine in WebSphere.  Based on the exception stack, what appears to be happening is that something in your web services engine is interacting with WebSphere's version and triggering a load for a dependency that WebSphere doesn't package.  Setting the environment to use your version will resolve that.

Note that WebSphere already includes Axis2, so unless you are strictly dependent on that specific point release, there's a very good chance that the best solution for you is just to rely on WebSphere's web services provider, rather than bringing your own.  That will greatly simplify your configuration, since you won't need to mess with class loading delegation settings or system properties disabling the web services provider.